# ¡Como saber si se ha realizado una actualizacion en una fila de Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla de pagos, que se va modificando de forma diaria, la cual tiene un PRESTAMOS, y un SALDO que le va quedando al cliente mediante va pagando de forma diaria, o semanal, pero la novedad esta en que quiero mostrar en la misma tabla una forma de saber si el cliente ha pagado en el día

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el QUERY con el que hago la consulta ala BD:

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `cliente` WHERE `prestamo` > 0 ORDER BY `fecha` ASC";
```

He estado leyendo que con `mysqli_affected_rows` muestra el numero de tablas afectadas cuando se hace una modificación, pero la idea es poder identificar la fila afectada y así saber quien ha pagado y así poder representarlo en la tabla.

El Historial de los pagos de los clientes los almaceno en otra tabla
con ID  - PAGO - FECHA, seria mas que todo saber como podría anidar una consulta que me haga esa validación o si la puedo hacer con PHP.

Comment: Sería de utilidad que pudieras agregar la estructura de tu tabla de datos

Comment: Añade la estructura de tus tablas en SQL con phpmyadmin, exportar y, con gusto, te indicaremos cómo actualizar esos datos calculados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero que la manera mas apropiada para esto es crear otra tabla que almacene el historial de pagos de los clientes y así podrás saber cuando y cuantos pagos han hecho, por ejemplo una tabla `historial_pagos` que tenga las siguiente columnas:

1. id cliente (id_cliente) int
2. cantidad pagada (cantidad) decimal
3. fecha en la que paga (fecha) date

Y después consultas a esa tabla para cambiar el estilo de las filas dependiendo de si ha hecho un pago el cliente.

Comment: Hola, disculpa esa parte olvide informarla, ya esa tabla la tengo, donde almacedo la ID, CANTIDAD, y la FECHA, como podria consultar a esa tabla y hacer la modificacion del estilo

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo separando tus tablas para tener una mejor estructura y más escalable, por la consulta que pones pareciera como si todo lo tienes en la misma tabla.
Sugiero dejar en una sola tabla la información de los clientes, luego crear otra para la información de los préstamos y que use claves foráneas para relacionarse con la de los clientes, y por último una más que guarde la información de los pagos y que a su vez también use claves foráneas para relacionarse con la de préstamos, con esto ya solo tendrías que hacer una consulta usando inner join para traer los datos que necesites de todas las tablas en una sola consulta
La otra ternativa si no quieres alterar tanto tu estructura de datos sería que agregues una nueva columna a tu tabla para registrar cuándo fue el último pago y la actualices cuando el sistema registra el nuevo pago
De todas formas te recomiendo mucho que mejor separes tu estructura de datos así es más fácil de mantener y de escalar tu base de datos y es necesario

Comment: Hola mis tablas estan separadas, esa que muestro es la consulta de una, pero en otra tabla se guarda la ID - ABONO - FECHA.